# Make: Redo some targets if configuration changes

Tags: configuration, makefile

I want to reexecute some targets when the configuration changes.

Consider this example:

I have a configuration variable (that is either read from environment variables or a config.local file):

```
CONF:=...
```

Based on this variable CONF, I assemble a header file conf.hpp like this:

```
conf.hpp:
    buildConfHeader $(CONF)
```

Now, of course, I want to rebuild this header if the configuration variable changes, because otherwise the header would not reflect the new configuration. But how can I track this with make? The configuration variable is not tied to a file, as it may be read from environment variables.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. Hopefully this will help anyone having the same problem:

I build a file name from the configuration itself, so if we have

```
CONF:=a b c d e
```

then I create a configuration identifier by replacing the spaces with underscores, i.e.,

```
null:=
space:= $(null) #
CONFID:= $(subst $(space),_,$(strip $(CONF))).conf
```

which will result in `CONFID=a_b_c_d_e.conf`

Now, I use this `$(CONFID)` as dependency for the `conf.hpp` target. In addition, I add a rule for `$(CONFID)` to delete old `.conf` files and create a new one:

```
$(CONFID):
    rm -f *.conf #remove old .conf files, -f so no error when no .conf files are found
    touch $(CONFID) #create a new file with the right name

conf.hpp: $(CONFID)
    buildConfHeader $(CONF)
```

Now everything works fine. The file with name `$(CONFID)` tracks the configuration used to build the current `conf.hpp`. If the configuration changes, then `$(CONFID)` will point to a non-existant `.conf` file. Thus, the first rule will be executed, the old conf will be deleted and a new one will be created. The header will be updated. Exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for `make` to know what to rebuild if the configuration changed via a macro or environment variable.

You can, however, use a target that simply updates the timestamp of `conf.hpp`, which will force it to always be rebuilt:

```
conf.hpp: confupdate
    buildConfHeader $(CONF)

confupdate:
    @touch conf.hpp
```

However, as I said, `conf.hpp` will always be built, meaning any targets that depend upon it will need rebuilt as well. A much more friendly solution is to generate the makefile itself. CMake or the GNU Autotools are good for this, except you sacrifice a lot of control over the makefile. You could also use a build script that creates the makefile, but I'd advise against this since there exist tools that will allow you to build one much more easily.

Comment: I am using this in a project where I am not allowed to change from make to CMake or anything else, but thank you for the idea.